# what is the `this` in a compiled jst template

Tags: javascript, ejs

When an ejs file compiles, it becomes a javascript function.  For example, this ejs file

```
<h3> Users Index</h3>
<ul>
  <% users.each(function (user) { %>
    <li><%= user.get("name") %></li>
  <% })%>
</ul>
```

compiles to this javascript function:

```
(function() { this.JST || (this.JST = {}); this.JST["users/index"] =     function(obj){var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.apply(__p,arguments);};with(obj||{}){__p.push('<h3> Users Index</h3>\n\n<ul>\n  ');  users.each(function (user) { ; __p.push('\n    <li>',  user.get("name") ,'</li>\n  ');  }); __p.push('\n</ul>\n\n');}return __p.join('');};
}).call(this);
```

In the above javascript function, what does the `this` refer to? (ie. a backbone view, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a self executing function construct like that

```
(function() { console.log(this) }).call(this);
```

You'll notice it'll output (Chrome console output)

```
Window {external: Object, chrome: Object, document: document, i: undefined, StackExchange: Object…}
```

So all this does is simply add the variable `JST` to the global (`window`) namespace so that it's accessible in every following script.

The line `this.JST || (this.JST = {});` will make sure that if `window.JST` (`window` = `this` as we saw) exists and if not it gets created and it's value will be an empty object (`this.JST = {}`).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks!